# Excel lockfile left, but not original

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, temporary-files

On MacOS, an excel file I need disappeared for whatever reason. When searching for it, I only find the file prefixed with ~$, I assume it is a lockfile. I don’t see it in my recently opened files either.

How can I recover my workbook from that lockfile on MacOS?

Comment: The lockfile does not contain any contents of the workbook. It exists to prevent multiple users from using the same file simultaneously.

Comment: And is my assumption of it being a lockfile correct? Maybe it’s not? @Brian

Comment: Yes, `~$` is the structure used for MSFT office lock files.

Comment: See if Time Machine has it. Even if you don't have a Time Machine drive, the Mac will still use local storage space to try keep recent changes. I can't test the theory, as I've never been without a dedicated TM backup. …and in future, make sure you have backups.